# Count the number of cards on a Trello board

Tags: trello, api

For a given Trello board, how can I get the total number of cards on it if the number of cards exceeds 999?

The [API documentation](https://trello.com/docs/api/board/index.html#get-1-boards-board-id-actions) (see `page`) implies this is not possible since `page` * `limit` cannot exceed 1000.

For example, when I call `https://api.trello.com/1/boards/ID/actions?key=KEY&token=TOKENfields=name&limit=999&page=1` it returns the following message.

> page * limit must be less than 1000, requested 1998

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get actions, but you're talking about cards.  Can you clarify what you want?

Comment: Hi Aaron, 
i need to count how many cards are included in a board.

Answer (score 4):

Enter this in the JS console of your trello board

```
$(".list-card").length
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the [API route to get cards](https://trello.com/docs/api/board/index.html#get-1-boards-board-id-cards), not the one for actions.  It would look something like:

https://api.trello.com/1/boards/ID/cards?key=KEY&token=TOKEN

Comment: i used this api, but it return 999 cards and searching for "page" in api documentations i saw "actions", so i tried to use boards/ID/actions. it would be great if /boards/ID/cards return also "Number Of Cards"

Comment: @AndreaBisello That route returns all of the cards matching `filter`.  There is no need to do any sort of paging.  Note that the default `filter` is `visible` - unless you specify something else, you are only getting non-archived cards on non-archived lists.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to [@everConfusedGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1181919/everconfusedguy)'s answer, but in plain JS (without jQuery).

Enter this into the console of the page:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".list-card").length
```

Comment: @everConfusedGuy's answer doesn't contain any jQuery. As he says in his answer, it's javascript that you execute in your console.

Answer (score -6):

I am using [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cardcounter-for-trello-be/jbdmgabkegidhagemkfdogmplgelaoab) extension for Chrome.

This extension show me the total cards that I have in my board.

[image]

Comment: This extension was built by the person who added this reply: @henrique-brugugnoli.
It does 2 things you need to know before installing:
1: It requires access to all data on your computer and the websites you visit, it means that the app or extension can access almost anything (webcam, 
personal files), inside or outside of your browser.
2. Past versions injected affiliate code, ~23 trackers slow down browser